# Stub Promise.all using sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stubbing, stubs

I have several promises that I am trying to resolve using Promise.all asynchronously as below:

```
model1.find({ _id: params.id }).limit(1).
        lean().then((data) => {
            let promises = [];
                let p1 = model2.find({ _id: '123' }).limit(1).lean().then((data) => {
                    return data;
                })
                promises.push(p1);
               let p2 = model3.find({ _id: '789' }).limit(1).lean().then((data) => {
                    return data;
                })
                promises.push(p2);
               let p3 = model4.find({ _id: '678' }).limit(1).lean().then((data) => {
                    return data;
                })
                promises.push(p3);

            Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
                data.forEach((entry) => {
                    let keys = Object.keys(entry);
                    result[keys[0]] = entry[keys[0]];
                });
                response.json(result);
            })
        })
```

How do I stub the above code using sinon and writing unit tests for them?
Or any other library that I can use to unit-test the above code effectively

Comment: You stub the four models, not `Promise.all`.

Comment: How stubbing the models going to serve the code coverage of this function?